# customize url when user wants to reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am working in a node js project. going page to page using redirect from server.js file. I have manually customized url using `window.history.pushState("","","custom.url.testing/taslim");` from html page script.

Now the problem is when ever user reload the page it shows `cannnot get /custom.url.testing/taslim`.

how can I customize url before reload operation after pressing reload button in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your node.js server to handle all your custom urls, and return the same as the route you want your user to load.

This might mean that you set up a wildcard rule so that anything with `/custom.url.testing/*` will load the same code.

this would probably look like

```
app.get("/custom.url.testing/*", function(req, res, next){
  // same as whatewer your default route  is
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });
```

for that url.